# How can I do for-loops with Android databinding?

Tags: android, mvvm, knockout.js, android-databinding

Most popular MVVM-frameworks allow some kind of loops for list type properties. For example Knockout has the [foreach-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html). It allows you to loop through the elements of the list property and for each element the markup contained in the foreach-loop is duplicated. Inside the copy, the current element is used as the context for data-binding.

I was looking for something similar in Android, but I only saw the possibility to bind a list to a specific ui-element. But this is bad with respect to declarativeness because I need to create a UI element in code.

Is there a way to simulate something similar using the data binding features from Android? If not, is there a workaround? Or a way to extend the binding syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible as is. The android databinding library uses static XML layout and binds values to attributes. Creating static layout dynamically is not supported and I assume won't ever be. If you want to create a view hierarchy dynamically you still should use views with adapters. That's something you can do with databindings. Just create your own databinding adapter for binding a list to a `RecyclerVier`. You could bind to a pair of `binding:iterator` and `binding:layout` attributes for example and set the `RecyclerVier.Adapter` inside the databinding adapter.

Answer (score 5):

As @tynn answered, this kind of api is not available.

To achieve the same result, you can setup an adapter for RecyclerView in XML itself. I have implemented this feature in my MVVM library. See [Setup RecyclerView from XML itself](https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm#data-binding-to-reduce-boilerplate).

Your XML will look as follows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    bind:items="@{vm.itemVms}"
    bind:layout_vertical="@{true}"
    bind:view_provider="@{@layout/row_item}" />

<!-- Same arguments for ViewPager-->
<android.support.v4.widget.ViewPager
    bind:items="@{vm.itemVms}"
    bind:view_provider="@{@layout/row_item}" />
```

Additionally, there is support for displaying different kinds of child views based on your ViewModel. See [Using different types of child views](https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm#using-different-views)

Comment: Great resource and interesting project! Thanks!